# Почему код выдает ошибку "Arrays are not allowed in class constants"? Как ее исправить?

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {

    const PHOTO_SIZES = array(
         1 => array(
            'width' => 122,
            'height' => 122
         ),
         2 => array(
            'width' => 60,
            'height' => 60
    )
);

(тут еще другой код. но он ошибку не выдает. если закомментировать код, который выше, ошибка исчезает.)
}
```

При запуске выдает ошибку:
"Arrays are not allowed in class constants". Как ее исправить?

P.S. если что, у меня верси PHP 7.1.

Comment: А у меня работает..

Comment: @entithat у меня тоже: `class Model_User
{
    const PHOTO_SIZES = array(
        1 => array(
            'width' => 122,
            'height' => 122
        ),
        2 => array(
            'width' => 60,
            'height' => 60
        )
    );
}

var_dump(Model_User::PHOTO_SIZES);`

Comment: Может у автора не та версия, о которой он думает?

Comment: @entithat скорее всего )

Comment: Нет, именно 7.1 у меня. Но страница ошибки немного другая. И у таблицы (если смотреть верстку страницы ошибки) классы -
 "xdebug-error xe-fatal-error". Может, нужно как-то xdebug настроить / обновить?

Comment: `phpinfo()` что показывает?

Comment: Да, вы правы, 5 версия. phpinfo() показал. А я указал в IDE 7 версию для проекта. И думал, что у меня седьмая. А оказывается нужно в OpenServer указывать. Спасибо за ответ.